# Why are CERT.SF and MANIFEST.MF almost identical in my apk generated by Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, certificate, manifest

In **CERT.SF**:
[CERT.SF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIu9f.png)

In **MANIFEST.MF**:
[MANIFEST.MF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CpFx.png)

As you see, they are different just in three lines in the beginning. I know both of files are used to verify the integrity of apk and CERT.SF should store the sha-256 digest of MANIFEST.MF. So they can't be identical in the other items.

By the way, I used V1 signature version because if you choose V2 signature verion, you'll get a signed apk only owning MANIFEST.MF in the folder MATE-INF when unzipping the apk-release.apk.